# Weird cacheing issues with heroku / memcache and dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memcached

Consider the following.  From my heroku console:

```
>> Rails.cache.stats
=> {"server_id"=>{"evictions"=>"0", "curr_items"=>"2064", "total_items"=>"18793", "bytes"=>"7674501", ...
>> Rails.cache.clear
=> [true]
>> Rails.cache.stats
=> {"server_id"=>{"evictions"=>"0", "curr_items"=>"2064", "total_items"=>"18793", "bytes"=>"7674501",
```

Super weird -- how can I clear my cache!!

---

Similar Issue ? : https://stackoverflow.com/q/7122513/192791

Comment: Have you tried a `Rails.cache.read('key')` where you know there's a value stored in the cache for that particular key. As @b-r-o-s mentioned stats aren't always updated immediately, but if you try to read from the cache then it should return nil straight away.

Comment: I'm facing something similar, I run a Rails.cache.clear and I must restart my instance if I want to see the cache reloaded. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect directly to the Dalli/memcahced client through the console and flush_all the cache clears.

i.e.

```
dc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211')
dc.flush_all
```

NOTE: the stats take a while to update, but the cache will definitely clear.

Comment: Note that `ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore` used flush_all when you run `clear` see the docs here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/dalli/1.0.5/ActiveSupport/Cache/DalliStore

Answer (score 1):

The **Expiring Cache** section at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-the-memcache-addon suggests using filters

```
after_save    :expire_contact_all_cache
after_destroy :expire_contact_all_cache

def expire_contact_all_cache
  Rails.cache.delete('Contact.all')
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work for fragments in the view, though -- does it?

Comment: Thanks for this -- I am not looking for an expiring cache strategy -- I want to know why Rails.cache.clear is not clearing the cache. (When I put out a new release -- I want to totally clear the cache)