# Rails Cache Action Won't Expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, memcached

I'm on Heroku and trying to implement caching in my Rails app, but I'm running into some problems that I don't understand.  I thought it would be easy after reading the Rails Guide and Heroku docs on caching strategies, but apparently doing something wrong.

Issue 1: view of action doesn't seem to expire
Issue 2: when I use :layout => false, both my admin and app layout are used (trying to only get the application layout)

Any help for this newbie would be most appreciated!

production.rb (also installed dalli per heroku documentation)

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true (added after reading http://bit.ly/oRKub1)
```

controller

```
layout 'admin'
caches_action :show, :layout => false

def show
  render :layout => 'application'
end

def update
  expire_action :action => :show
end
```

I tried to test the expiration by changing a product, but the show view does not expire.  So when I look at edit view for products, which I'm not caching, I can see the change saved (just added a word to the title), but when I view show, it still has the old info.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the aspen/bamboo stack I dont think caching works in rails as the apps are fronted by varnish which does caching for you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "caches_action", but you can try to expire manually all cache and see what happens.

```
def update
  # expire_action :action => :show
  Rails.cache.clear
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If is there any caching issue than  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7122962/3962760) link will help you to find solution. 
You can connect directly to `dalli/memcached` client through heroku console and then use flush_all to flush the cache.

Or refer this [google-groups link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/heroku/2XgAouD7RgM)